# How to extract the root directory from a path

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to make a regular expression just by taking the first directory of a route.

For example:

```
/home/oracle/file1.dbf
/home/oracle/file2.dbf
/usr/oracle/file3.dbf
/usr/oracle/file3.dbf
```

You should return:

```
/home
/home
/usr
/usr
```

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT substr(file_name,instr(file_name,'/')-1) as FILE_NAME
FROM   dba_data_files;
```

Comment: And why doesn't your query work?

Comment: This does not use regular expressions, but simple string functions. regexpr_substr could be a regex solution

Comment: Why do you have "regular expression" in the title? That's not good for two reasons: First, the problem has a much more efficient solution **without** regular expressions (as MT0 has shown); and second, your title should always describe the problem you are trying to solve, not the solution you have in mind. (Which in this case didn't use regular expressions anyway, but even if it did...) A title like "How to extract the root directory from a path" would make much more sense and wouldn't suggest that only one specific approach should be used.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you very much for your advice, I will immediately change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is [`SUBSTR( string, start_position, substring_length )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) so you want to start from the 1st character and the length is the position of the 2nd occurrence of the slash character which can be found using [`INSTR( string, substring, start_position, occurrence )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
         file_name,
         1,
         INSTR( file_name, '/', 1, 2 ) - 1
       ) AS root_directory
FROM   dba_data_files;
```

Comment: It may be better to concatenate a slash to `file_name` first, otherwise the solution will fail on an input like `/usr`.